# Delegate And Observer Design for Updating Data throughout an App

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

I'm building an iPhone app that has a central class, M, that gets a bunch of data from a Web API. Whenever this class gets data, it has to update two controllers, say A and B. To support this both A and B are listed under an interface that has an update command. A and B also need to be able to query data from class M, so I've added a handle to M in both A and B.

The problem is that is setup isn't very modular. I'm looking for ways to clean up the design.

EDIT - Also, class M doesn't have any preconceived notion of what the exact type of the class A and B will be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as you're proposing on the title: use the *observer* pattern. `A` and `B` are *observers* (that implement an *observer* protocol) to `M`, which is the *subject*. When you update the observers, also provide the *event* data through the update method, maybe as a handle to a *subject* protocol that `M` implements. This way, `A` and `B` are decoupled from `M` through the *observer* and *subject* protocols.